# Is it possible to get authenticated user's friend's tweets and download them from twitter?

Tags: twitter

I need to download my friends tweets. I've found some applications online that help getting a user's own status messages. Is there any application or a way (in any programming language) to get other persons status messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following URI will get you the info you need:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=<insert_screen_name_here>
```

You can change the `.json` to `.xml` to get them in XML if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Look into a couple of these libraries, I'm sure one of them will allow you to use your own authentication info to get your friend's nonpublic tweets.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries